# Signature field in exported PDF?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice

I'm using LibreOffice to create fillable PDF forms which works like a charm.
I'd like to add PDF signature field(s) to my exported PDF documents so that they can be signed with Adobe Reader. Is there a way to achieve this with LibreOffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I do not think LibreOffice can create digital signature fields.  Here are some other ideas:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/166875/create-fillable-or-editable-fields-in-a-pdf
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51090/how-do-i-create-a-pdf-file-that-can-be-digitally-signed

Then there is the standard choice - the full [Adobe Acrobat (PDF)](http://www.aacrjournals.org/site/downloads/DigitalInstr/creating_digital_signatures.pdf).